Euler method stability for systems of differential equations.
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
I happen to read on several papers about a stability condition for Euler Method for
$$
\dot{x} = \on{f}\left(t,x\right).
$$
Let $\on{J}\left(t\right)$ be the Jacobian matrix of $\on{f}$ and $\epsilon$ the step, then Euler Method is stable if
$$
\max_i \left\vert 1 + \epsilon\lambda_{i}
\left(\on{J}\left(t\right)\right)\right\vert < 1,\quad\forall\ t\geq 0
$$
where $\lambda_{i}
\left(\on{J}\left(t\right)\right)$ represents the $i$-th eigenvalue of $\on{J}\left(t\right)$.
The problem is that I can not happen to find a proof anywhere of that assertion.
Can someone guide me on the proof or recommend somewhere I can read it?
Thanks.

Could you elaborate on how "stable" is defined in these papers? It has to apply on the combination of ODE and method. Is this a matrix norm, or some other measure of the matrix, like the spectral radius?

They don't give a definition of the numerical stability, they just say Euler forward method is stable if $max_{i=1,..,n} |1-\epsilon \lambda_i(J(t))| \leq 1$ for all t where $\lambda$ means taking the autovalues of $J$.

This highly depends on the notion of "stability" you have in mind. However, looking at the condition $\left\|I+\epsilon J(t)\right\| < 1$ is seems like the "stability" in question is the numerical stability of the forward Euler method.
The method can be written down as an iterative process
\begin{align}
 x_n = \left(I+\epsilon J(t) \right)x_{n-1}.
\end{align}
For the moment, lets assume that $J(t)$ does not depend on $t$, $J(t) = J$. Then the scheme above turns into
\begin{align}
x_n = \left(I+\epsilon J \right)^n x_{0}
\end{align}
which is essentially power iteration (without normalization) for the matrix $A:=I+\epsilon J$. The limiting behaviour of this method is
\begin{align}
x_n \approx \lambda_p^n v_p
\end{align}
where $v_p$ is the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue of $A$ such that the scalar product $(x_0, v_p)$ is not 0. This is ok when computing precisely but becomes an issue what computing on PC in floating point arithmetic.
Let $v_1$ denote the eigenvector corresponding to the highest eigenvalue. When computing in the floating point arithmetic, roughly speaking, the scalar product $(x_0, v_1)$ will always be nonzero and $x_n \approx \lambda_1^n v_1$ for large $n$. If $\lambda_1 > 1$ this leads to an exponential blowup of the solution. (This is for sure ok for some equations but there are many without exponential solutions. :)
The condition $\left\|I+\epsilon J\right\| < 1$ ensures that $\lambda_1 < 1$ and therefore prevents the exponential blowup. The usual remedy in the case $\lambda_1 > 1$ is lowering the step length $\epsilon$, which might be impractical for some equations, or using a different scheme. I highly recommend trying this out by programming the method and playing with different $\epsilon$ and $x_0$'s.
The conclusion, that $\left\|I+\epsilon J\right\| > 1$ is potentially not safe, can be straightforwardly extended to the $J(t)$ case, although the precise analysis is probably more tricky.

Thanks, I just realized I forgot the $\lambda_i$ inside the absolute value which is actually the part that is puzzling me, so I corrected the question. I did have the same impression of what you are explaining, but I think I realized it now, because taking the eigenvalue of $J$ and substracting it to I getting lower than 1 will mean that the eigenvalue of $|I+\epsilon J|$ will also be smaller than 1 and the same result will arise. Thanks.

What you describe is, in the general non-linear case, not the method itself, but the propagation of small changes in the initial values to changes in the iteration sequence. Which is of course the correct thing to explore.

@LutzLehmann Yes, that is pretty much what I had in mind. Sadly, my insight into $A$ stability and other stabilities is limited, feel free to edit the answer to your liking.
